# Configuration problems with ALB / Lambda and Target Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

After the Lambda script triggers via ALB how do I redirect the user back to the Target Groups (servers) ?

Current Setup

- ALB (Application Load Balancer)
- ALB "Authenticate" set as Cognito
- ALB "Forward to" set as Lambda Function (Python script)

On root path “https://site.domain.com/” (ALB) Cognito is triggered to prompt users for authentication.
After successfully authenticating the traffic is passed to the Lambda script using an ALB rule to verify the JWT, I'm returned a 502 Bad Gateway because the Lambda function is not handling the traffic correctly.

1. Is the lambda script responsible for redirecting traffic back to the “Target Groups” (is it possible to complete this task within the script) OR should I set “302” redirect to return the user to the application landing page ?
2. Is it an option to setup a second ALB rule on root path “/“ to pass traffic to the identity Pool

   - First Rule (Cognito Authentication / Forward to Lambda Function)
   - Add a second rule to direct traffic to Target Group on the root path 
     (There seems to be a priority in which rule is triggered first and second)
3. Or is it a case I need to configure separate URL paths to handle authentication and backend server traffic

   - https://site.domain.com/ (Cognito Authentication / Forward to Lambda Function)
   - https://site.domain.com/application (Backend application)

Comment: Your question body doesn't seem to mention the `502` error from the question title.  Also unclear, are you using [ALB/Cognito integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/)?  Because if you are, I'm not sure I understand the role of the Lambda function.  If you're not, is there a reason not to?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the details with further information.